# Is Wubi still supported?

Tags: ubuntu, wubi

I'm a Windows user who is dipping their toes into the Linux pool.

I heard Ubuntu is a good distro for newbies, and I was interested in Wubi.exe because I could try Ubuntu without committing.

However, the most recent version of Wubi is 12.10, and (at the time of this question) Ubuntu is now on 15.04.

Is Wubi still even supported? Should I just get another hard drive and do a full install?

Comment: You don't need another *drive*, you need some *partitions* of your disk. So defragment and resize your Windows partition to get about 60Gbytes available in a contiguous disk partition

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Ah, okay. Still, the question remains. Is 15.04 that much of a step up from 12.10?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.10 is [no longer supported](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases).

Comment: Worth considering installing a free VM solution (VMware / VirtualBox) and install Ubuntu or any other distro within there.  No hard disk partitioning required.

Comment: @steve I can't believe I didn't think of that. I have VirtualBox on my computer already too, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`wubi` has not seen any active development over the last couple of years, so I would advise against using it if you want to be future-proof.

Having said that, I would also advise to install [Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop) as the version numbering in Ubuntu [works differently from Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/572628/how-do-i-decide-what-version-of-ubuntu-to-install-what-is-the-difference-betwe) and the latest is not necessarily the greatest... (*E.G. the most stable version...*)

So [head over here if you want to dual-boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/581902/how-to-efficiently-partition-a-single-windows-ubuntu-dual-boot-disk) and then [over here when you're ready to install Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu).

<sub>Oh, and if you want some [backups this is an interesting read as well](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc).</sub>